# Java Spring - how to send byte[] within a DTO

Tags: angular, spring, typescript, rest, byte

I work for a server-side application and I have a problem: on front-end, a Blob ins't converted properly to Excel file if the byte[] is sended within a dto

For a **POST** request, from back-end(spring) if I send byte[], it arrived well in front-end
(angular, typescript), but if I send byte[] within a DTO object, it become wrong and I don't understand why. The meaning of "become wrong": if I try to create a Excel file from byte[] (which is Blob in typescript) this won't work - the resulting excel file cannot be opened, and if I try to open it with a text editor (e.g notedpad++) I see that there are bytes characters (e.g "UEsDBBQACAgIAC2oPVQAAAAAAAAAAAA" and so on) which is wrong, because a normal Excel file is seen in a different way with a text editor.

Now the code:

**1. The variant without DTO (this works)**

Java:

```
@PostMapping("/exportData")
@Transactional
public byte[] exportData(@RequestBody ExportRequestDTO exportRequestDTO){
    // other stuff
    byte[] a = new byte[5];
    return a;
}
```

Typescript:

```
requestFileForExport(exportRequestDTO : ExportRequestDTO):Observable<HttpResponse<Blob>>{
        return this.httpClient.post(`${this.exportDataURL}`,exportRequestDTO, {responseType: 'blob',observe: 'response'});
  }
```

And:

```
this.exportDataService.requestFileForExport(exportRequestDTO).subscribe((data:HttpResponse<Blob>)=>{
  let blob = new Blob([data.body], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
  saveAs(blob,"file.xlsx");
    });
```

I can open resulting excel file (with MS Excel) and looks fine. This is how it looks if I open with a text editor:
[image]
**2 .The variant with DTO (which create a wrong excel file - so this variant don't work. WHY?)**

Java:

```
public class FileDTO {
         private byte bytes[];
         private String fileName;
         // constructors, getters and setters
}
```

And:

```
@PostMapping("/exportData")
@Transactional
public FileDTO exportData(@RequestBody ExportRequestDTO exportRequestDTO){
    FileDTO a = new FileDTO();
    // other stuff
    return a;
}
```

Typescript:

```
export class FileDTO {

bytes:Blob;
fileName:string;

constructor(bytes: Blob, fileName: string) {
    this.bytes = bytes;
    this.fileName = fileName;
   }
}
```

And:

```
requestFileForExport(exportRequestDTO : ExportRequestDTO):Observable<FileDTO>{
     return this.httpClient.post(`${this.exportDataURL}`,exportRequestDTO);
}
```

And:

```
  this.exportDataService.requestFileForExport(exportRequestDTO).subscribe(data=>{
  let res = data;
  let blob = new Blob([res.bytes], {type: 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet'});
  saveAs(blob,"file.xlsx");
 });
```

I can't open resulting excel file with MS Excel. Also, this is how it looks if I open with a text editor
[image]

saveAs is from file-saver js, but the result is the same (variant 1 works, variant 2 not) if I tried to do a manual file save - **the problem is file itself, not save part**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jackson serializes byte array to base64 by default, so you will have to decode it first..

Comment: yes, I converted the received "Blob" to a base64 string, and with string type, I converted to a real Blob object; also, I used this for conversion (base64 string to Blod) https://gist.github.com/Marceloalves6/d1f590437f7fe45ac6832e5177c84be6